# Using JSON.NET to serialize to XmlDictionaryWriter

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json.net

I am converting all of our projects to use JSON.NET rather than DataContractJsonSerializer. How do I use JSON.NET to write to an XmlDictionaryWriter?

Current Implementation (using DataContractJsonSerializer):

```
public class ErrorBodyWriter : BodyWriter
{
    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        if (Format == WebContentFormat.Json)
        {
            // How do I use json.net below?
            var serializer = 
                new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ErrorMessage));
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, Error);
        }
        else { // xml }
    }
    public ErrorBodyWriter() : base(true){}
    public ErrorMessage Error { get; set; }
    public WebContentFormat Format { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. WCF is primarily XML-based, and to support JSON it was defined a [JSON-to-XML mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx) which if one wrote XML in a very specific format, and the underlying XML writer could produce JSON, then the proper JSON would be output.

The default WCF JSON serializer (`DataContractJsonSerializer`) knows how to write JSON to a XML writer using that mapping. JSON.NET doesn't. So one option is to write to a memory stream using JSON.NET, then *read it into XML* using the WCF JSON/XML reader, then use that to write to the `XmlDictionaryWriter`. The code would look somehow like the snippet below (written on notepad, some kinks may need to be addressed):

```
public class ErrorBodyWriter : BodyWriter
{
    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        if (Format == WebContentFormat.Json)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Error);
            var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            using (var reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(jsonBytes, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max)) {
                writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
            }
        }
        else { // xml }
    }
    public ErrorBodyWriter() : base(true){}
    public ErrorMessage Error { get; set; }
    public WebContentFormat Format { get; set; }
}
```